# Is there a way to know which full URL the Spring controller is going to map?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-web

I have a Spring Controller,

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

@Autowired
private EmployeeService employeeService;

/**
 * returns all the employees in the datastore.
 * 
 * @return list of all employees.
 */
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getAllEmployees() {
    return convertObjectListToJSONArray(this.employeeService.listEmployees());
}

/**
 * adds an employee in the data-store.
 * 
 * @param employee
 *            employee to add in the data-store.
 * @return request status.
 */
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?> addEmployee(UriComponentsBuilder uriCBuilder, @RequestBody Employee employee) {
    Employee e = this.employeeService.getEmployeeById(employee.getId());
    if(null != e) {
        throw new EmployeeConflictException(); 
    }
    this.employeeService.addEmployee(employee);
    UriComponents uriComponents = uriCBuilder.path("/cmpe281Pratik021/rest/employee/{id}")
            .buildAndExpand(employee.getId());
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setLocation(uriComponents.toUri());
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

But, when I hit http://localhost:8080/employee it gives an error 404.
Is there a way to print to full url which this Spring controller is going to be mapped?

Comment: It seems your context is missing in the URL you are hitting.  http://localhost:8080/<Context-Name>/employee

Comment: How did you deploy this application? was it a .war file? or Spring Boot? If a .war you need the contextPath (name of .war) as well. `http://localhost:8080/<name of war>/employee`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to print to full url which this Spring controller is
>   going to be mapped ?

You can enable the below logging property:

```
log4j.category.org.springframework.web=INFO
```

Now, if you restart your Tomcat (or any server), then during the start up, when Spring container initializing the `DispactherServlet` and `HandlerMapping`, it will print all the identified mappings (from various `Controller` classes) to the logs so that you can actually verify what mappings are going to be served by the `Controller` classes.

**P.S.: This logging is just to list/log all the controller mappings, which will be helpful to debug/solve the problems**

Comment: I'm gonna try this. Hopefully It'll solve the problem.

Comment: It will help you to list all the mappings, which will be helpful to solve the problem

Comment: how to enable this property?

Comment: do you have log4j properties in your server ?

Comment: The log says - `2016-11-07T10:20:07.422957+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-11-07 10:20:07 INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:543 - Mapped "{[/employee],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String edu.pratiksanglikar.cmpe281.hw3.extracredit.controllers.EmployeeController.getAllEmployees()` but the request `http://localhost:8080/employees` is returning `HTTP 404`. Any inputs? related source files can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459550/i-am-trying-to-build-an-application-using-spring-mvc-and-cant-figure-out-why-th)